# Lat and Long in BigQuery, how do I find the country, continent, city and suburb?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, location, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have a table in BigQuery that has specific lat/long locations around the world. I want to be able to join to a table and get the Continent, Country, City and Suburb of that geopoint.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some table with the country data, that describes the countries, cities etc as polygons. Note that this might be complicated depending on your needs - different jurisdictions might have different ideas about country boundaries.

Once you have these - you can join with your data using `ST_Intesects` condition, like `ST_Intersects(reference_geography, ST_GeogPoint(lon, lat))` (note lon:lat coordinate order, rather than lat:lot frequently used in other contexts).

One such dataset you might use is Open Street Maps data in BigQuery public dataset. Here is how to query a single point:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION tag_value(tags ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>, name STRING)
RETURNS STRING AS (
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(tags) WHERE key = name)
);

SELECT 
  tag_value(all_tags, 'admin_level') as admin_level,
  tag_value(all_tags, 'name') as name
FROM (
  SELECT all_tags 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features_multipolygons`
  WHERE ST_Intersects(geometry, ST_GeogPoint(-122.193476, 47.696147))
    AND tag_value(all_tags, 'admin_level') IS NOT NULL
)
ORDER BY admin_level;
```

Result:

```
Row   admin_level    name
1     2              United States
2     4              Washington
3     6              King County
4     8              Kirkland
```

Or join with your data

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION tag_value(
    tags ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>, name STRING)
RETURNS STRING AS (
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(tags) WHERE key = name)
);

WITH reference_data AS (
  SELECT 
    CAST(tag_value(all_tags, 'admin_level') AS INT64) as admin_level,
    tag_value(all_tags, 'name') as name,
    geometry
  FROM (
    SELECT all_tags, geometry
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features_multipolygons`
    WHERE SAFE_CAST(tag_value(all_tags, 'admin_level') AS INT64) IS NOT NULL
  )
), my_points AS (
  SELECT 1 as id, ST_GeogPOINT(90.3781398, 23.766686606993) as p
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as id, ST_GeogPOINT(-74.013506, 40.7130162636655) as p
)
SELECT id, admin_level, name 
FROM reference_data JOIN my_points
ON ST_Intersects(geometry, p)
ORDER BY id, admin_level;
```

One current restriction of BigQuery - you cannot use outer join here (e.g. LEFT JOIN) - the performance would be much worse.

```
id  admin_level name
1   2   বাংলাদেশ
1   4   ঢাকা বিভাগ
1   5   ঢাকা জেলা
2   2   United States
2   4   New York
2   5   New York
2   6   New York County
2   7   Manhattan
2   10  Manhattan Community Board 1
```

Being open source volunteer-maintained data, the quality of OSM dataset varies among locations, so check data before usage.

Comment: That is extremely helpful. I have a table of GEOPOINTs and would want these details per row. Could you help me. My table looks like the below, what code changes would I need to make?

my_point
POINT(90.3781398 23.766686606993)
POINT(-74.013506 40.7130162636655)

Comment: I've added a join example