# How can I compare two coordinates to see if they are in the same country in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, geolocation, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have 1 table in BigQuery with longitude and latitude columns.
I have another table that has all the countries and their corresponding coordinates.

How can I compare city A's coordinate to see if it matches a country's coordinate?

I tried this, where `geography_2` is the Geography object for Peru as a country (created from the coordinates)  while `geography_1` is the Geography for an area within Peru:

I tired to compare both but it returns false.

```
SELECT ST_COVERS(geography_1, geography_2) 
FROM (SELECT  ST_GEOGPOINT(-79.036889, -8.123089) as geography_1, 
ST_GEOGPOINT(-75.015152, -9.189967) as geography_2) --peru
```

I have tried `ST_WITHIN` and `ST_INTERSECTS` also, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`-75.015152, -9.189967` does not represent Peru, it is a single point somewhere in Peru, probably centroid - but it does not describe Peru boundaries, and is not enough to establish if a point is within Peru.

You can also check the definitions of the functions you tried using:

- `ST_WITHIN` returns true if a point is within a polygon. That's a right function to use to see if a point is within country boundaries (with boundaries described as polygon). But you don't have a polygon - you have a single point.
- `ST_INTERSECTS` returns true if the shapes intersect, i.e. have common points. With two points as arguments, this is only possible if the two points are the same, i.e. it only works for exactly the same point as the one used to "represent" Peru.

To determine country you need a description of the country boundary, as a polygon. One dataset you can use in BigQuery is OSM data. See how to use it and how to determine a country in a recent question:

[Lat and Long in BigQuery, how do I find the country, continent, city and suburb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851805/lat-and-long-in-bigquery-how-do-i-find-the-country-continent-city-and-suburb)

Comment: Thank you. As I had no experience in geospatial data, I realised afterwards that these were points and not boundaries. I will give this a try.